# Setting a custom object relationship with the SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, lookup

I've been using the SOAP API to load different SObjects into an org. When I have a relationship, I can normally use an external ID as follows in order to set up relationships that exist between objects:

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
Account acc = new Account();
acc.setExternalId__c(ACC_EXT_ID);
opp.setAccount(opp);
```

This creates a lookup from an opportunity to an account that I have the external id for.

however, for some reason I have run into a situation where the API is not offering me a setter method with a signature that I can use to perform the above.

I am being offered:

```
myCustomObj.setAnotherCustomObj__c(String AnotherCustomObj__c)
```

and

```
myCustomObj.setAnotherCustomObj__r(QueryResult AnotherCustomObj__c)
```

**whereas**, in order to use the external ids in the same way as I have been doing, I would need:

```
myCustomObj.setAnotherCustomObj__r(AnotherCustomObj__c anotherCO)
```

Does anyone know why I am not being offered this method signature?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As @superfell suggested, I'll post the field definition:

[image: From Field List on FP_Order__c object]

[image: Order_Status__c lookup field definition]

In addition, and along the same lines, I have run into an issue trying to set the Owner of the Order_Status__c object using an external ID. I was hoping to be able to do the following:

```
Order_Status__c orderStatus = new Order_Status__c();
User owner = new user();
owner.setUserExtId__c(USER_EXT_ID);
orderStatus.setOwner(owner);
```

yet I am not being offered a method on the Order_Status__c object whereby I can set the owner using a *User* object. Instead the methods I am being offered by the SOAP API are:

```
setOwner(String Owner__c)
setOwner(Name Owner)
setOwnerId(String OwnerId)
```

In order to use these method, I would first have to select information (e.g. the owner id) from the database, whereas I would ideally like to set the Owner using an external id which I would already have.

Comment: Do you have any ext. id / unique field on the lookup target (`AnotherCustomObj__c`)? If you do - maybe you've marked it as ext. id it after you downloaded the WSDL - can you obtain fresh one and regenerate your classes?

Comment: Definitely have a live ext id that has been included in the WSDL as I can use it in a lookup from another object.

Comment: Have you tried constructing a QueryResult, placing a object instance in it and setting the field that represents the external reference? This is broadly how it works when using the Partner API, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17660/create-a-record-in-an-object-with-lookup-fields-through-java-soap/17672#17672

Answer (score 1):

Your AnotherCustomObj__r relationship is a parent to child relationship, not a lookup, in these case, the child object has a lookup to the parent, the parent doesn't have a direct lookup to the child (as there can be many child rows)

Comment: it doesn't look like that's the case, the question uses the opportunity -> account relationship as an example which implies a lookup relationship not a parent to child

Comment: yes, oppty -> account is perfectly valid, the signature of the relationship in the question indicates though that this is a parent-child relationship.

Comment: doesn't the __r just imply a relationship which can be either?  i.e. opportunity.parent_object__r = new Parent_Object__c() or (select (select Opportunities__r) from Parent_Object__c)

Comment: __r implies relationship of either direction, but because the parameter is a queryresult (a collection of records), rather than a single record,it can be inferred that this is a parent-child relationship.

Comment: Thanks but it is definitely a child to parent (lookup) relationship. I can easily check using workbench and the relationship is there.

Comment: post some specifics then, like a screen shot of the field definition.